# Ambient occlusion from high to low poly

Tags: texture-baking

this is the first question that I post here, I want to know how the ambient occlusion bake works due to the work I did on these 2 models [image: high poly](high poly is still wip) [image: low poly]

and this is the AO bake I managed to make
[image: AO bake]

I'm a complete noob when it comes to creating textures through bake, how can I avoid all that problems and artifacts in bake? for example the grid in the center has completely black results whereas the middle plate of the grip has a good result

Answer (score 1):

One cause of these artifacts may be hidden, but "set as to render", objects. If some of their faces might overlap to your active object during the baking.

Even your high poly object can cause this if you don't correctly enable the option "bake selected to active".

[image]

Example:

[image]

Low and highpoly

[image]

Object are in the same location, so faces overlap themeselves or are occluded

[image]

Image above is the baked with with the option disabled

[image]

This is if it is enable. You must select the highpoly, and THEN the lowpoly in order to get this result.

Someone asked for a moon? :-)

Comment: Yeah I checked the option selected to active and all useless objects in the scene, I was searching for a theory explanation of ambient occlusion because as I say I don't know a lot about baked textures, btw I joined all the objects of the high poly and the result is really good, I'm sooo happy :)

Comment: If you don't know "what" AO is you can give a look to this [answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7816/what-is-ambient-occlusion), if you would like to know in which way AO can be useful in computer graphics...well it will probably deserve a big and surely quite interisting answer...baking it is just tip of the iceberg

Comment: I want to know in details how get good ambient occlusion bake when baking from high poly to low poly, for transfer AO informations to low poly :) I know it is a big question, maybe an external link could be usefull according to stack exchange politics (I'm sorry for my english)