# Baking AO from High Poly to Low Poly gives weird result

Tags: texturing, baking

So I have this High Poly altar that I want to make into a low poly.

[image]

I've created the lowpoly version.

[image]

I've already baked the normals and it worked perfectly but once I've wanted to bake the AO, it gave me this strange result.

[image]

You can see that in some places it gave me something that seems relatively right (for example at the right of the picture you can recognise some parts of the indents that I have) but overall it gives me all those incoherent areas.

Ive already looked at [this topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34029/ambient-occlusion-from-high-to-low-poly) that seemed to correspond to my problem (I have other hidden objects) but I had already checked "selected to active" and selected the right models but still have the same problem.

Does anyone have any idea what's happening ? (I'm using 2.80 btw)

Comment: Are you sure, you applied rotation and scale to your low poly object?

Comment: Yep everything seems to be normal here