# Scene turns black after render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I made a quick blend and rendered it, saved up, and opened it back up later and everything's black? In LookDev and rendered view. I must of accidentally pressed something. I've looked through everything I can think of and have no idea what's gone wrong?
It's all my meshes/materials, I've tried answers mentioned in other questions as well. 
Any advice will help thanks[image: scene]

EDIT: For more information i've uploaded the file to dropbox, if you want to have a look at all the settings, but it happened after i rendered and re-opened the project so the settings weren't adjusted

[project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2zrt6742cypkxv/Lvl%20up%20Gem.blend?dl=0)

Also here is what it did look like before from the render: [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6nnhd9xnq1a6lq/Gem%20focus%20w_%20rocks0013.png?dl=0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scene renders black with ambient occlusion turned off in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50465/scene-renders-black-with-ambient-occlusion-turned-off-in-cycles)

Comment: Thanks, No I've tried all of that, I've got the lights hooked up right and im in Eevee, switched between both to test and all the settings

Comment: I don't think there's enough information to identify the problem just from your description and screenshot.

Comment: I think your material node was unlinked to the material output node.