# No light sources but object illuminated

Tags: light

My set has no light sources and no environment maps, resulting in black background - however, the objects are still illuminated. Have I enabled some obscure setting by mistake?

PS. This is in Cycles. When switched to Eevee, everything is back as expected.

[image]

Comment: in Properties > World, are you sure all options are disabled in Ray Visibility? Also, is Ambient Occlusion disabled?

Comment: Oh no, it was Ambient Occlusion. So ambient occlusion does not multiply colour with the shader output? Ie. if the raytraced object is dark, why does AO illuminate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you've enabled Ambient Occlusion. Ambient Occlusion is a fake light that was mostly used in Blender Render to improve the shadows. I'm not sure it's still very useful with 2.8 except maybe for some effects like baking shadows...

Vader explanation [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7816/what-is-ambient-occlusion). Manual explanation [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/world/ambient_occlusion.html).

[image]